# Click UITableViewCell to set focus in UITextField in iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder, ipad

I have seen related questions asking how to set focus at startup with firstResponder, but this is a little different.

When I click on a certain UITableViewCell, I want to set the focus in a specific UITextField.  Is there a way to set the focus of the UITextField in this manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override TouchesBegan on your custom TableViewCell to make the UITextField as the first responder

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have that cell you want then all you need to do.

[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];

Also remember the setTags:(NSUInteger*) and  viewWithTag:  Methods to get cell subviews you have placed.